# Difference between awsdms_apply_exceptions and awsdms_validation_failures_v1 in AWS DMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms

I am trying to learn the nitty gritty of AWS DMS. I came across an interesting section that talks about failures and troubleshooting during and after a DMS migration. There was one part that was a little confusing:

It looks like Failures during Migration go into **awsdms_apply_exceptions** but further down the line they indicate that for troubleshooting failures you can look at **awsdms_validation_failures_v1** table.

What is the difference between these two?